# run external process in integrated terminal without task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In an extension, I'm trying to implement a `TextEditorCommand` in response to which the document in the active editor is processed by an external program. I managed to do so by registering a function with the command, within which a `Task` object is created and executed:

in function `activate`:

```js
vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand('extension.command', process);
```

in function `process(textEditor)`:

```js
const document = textEditor.document;

const task = new vscode.Task(
    {type: ''},
    vscode.TaskScope.Workspace,
    extensionDisplayName,
    extensionName,
    new vscode.ProcessExecution(executable, [fileName].concat(args)));

vscode.tasks.executeTask(task);
```

This works, except that executing a task leads [all open documents to be saved](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21342), which is unnecessary and may be unwanted; I only need the active editor document to be saved, which I can do myself.

Therefore my question: Is it possible to run an external process in the integrated terminal without a `Task`?

I checked whether I can execute the `ProcessExecution` on its own, without passing it to a `Task`, but that doesn't seem possible.

I also tried to directly create a terminal, but `vscode.window.createTerminal` does not provide the option to specify an executable, just a shell – though I might simply pretend that my executable is a shell?

<del>Moreover, I already failed at creating any kind of terminal; putting
````typescript
vscode.window.createTerminal(extensionDisplayName);
````
into the `activate` function seems to have no effect whatsoever.</del>

*Turns out the transpiler process wasn't running, so my code never made it into the running extension.*

I could simply use node's `child_process.spawn`, but then the process would not be attached to VS Code's integrated terminal.

---

**Update:** Specifying an arbitrary executable as the "shell" running in the `Terminal` works.

However, it seems currently impossible to keep the terminal tab open after the process ended, so a shell or another wrapper is necessary.

But then it's impossible to get the exit status of the actual (wrapped) process, except maybe by having the wrapper write it to the terminal and parsing it's text content... nah, impossible too. Ugh

Comment: you can type text to the active terminal and build the command you want: [workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-via-a-keybinding)

Comment: @rioV8, how can I make that cross-platform / cross-shells? E.g. bash under Linux, PowerShell under Windows?

Comment: extension `ms-python` is able to activate the python virtual environment in any shell, you can have a look at the code

Comment: @rioV8, good idea.

Comment: @rioV8, doesn't work for me, see update.